# Problems using `elsif` in a `sort` block

Tags: ruby

I have this array:

```
ary = [[1, 6, 7], [1, 4, 9], [1, 8, 3]]
```

I want to sort it by the first odd number, or the last number if they are all even, in each subarray.

Since the first element in each array is the same object `1` for this particular `ary`, I can solve this like this:

```
ary2 = ary.sort_by { |a, b, c| b.odd? ? b : c }
```

But when I try a more general one:

```
arr2 = ary.sort_by { |a, b, c| a.odd? ? a : b.odd? ? b : c }
```

`ary2` comes back unsorted.

I tried removing the ternary operators like this:

```
ary2 = ary.sort_by do |a, b, c|
  if a.odd? 
    a
  elsif b.odd?
    b
  else
    c
  end
end
```

with the same effect (i.e., none).

Is there some reason that `elsif` can't be used in blocks passed to the `sort_by` method?

---

Edit: Axiac pointed out the problem with my logic. It looks like conditional logic has to deal with all of the possible permutations of odd and even values. This works:

```
arr2 = arr.sort_by do |a, b, c| 
  if a.odd?
    if b.odd?
      if c.odd?
        [a, b, c]
      else
        [a, b]
      end
    elsif c.odd?
      [a, c]
    else
      a
    end
  elsif b.odd?
    if c.odd?
      [b, c]
    else
      b
    end
  else
    c
  end
end
```

Maybe there's a more succinct and less brittle way to do it, but it's probably a good idea to do it this way instead:

```
arr2 = arr.sort_by do |sub_arr|
  temp = sub_arr.select do |e|
    e.odd?
  end
  temp.empty? ? Array(sub_arr.last) : temp
end
```

I'll see myself out.

Comment: It is not because of the ternary operators or the `if`/`elsif`. Your algorithm is flawed. The `a.odd?` test passes and the block returns `1` for all elements. `sort_by` correctly concludes the array is already sorted.

Comment: @axiac Ouch. So it is! :facepalm: Thank you. I knew there was  a reason I didn't want to post this.

Comment: "And I want to sort it by odd numbers..." is not clear, since you are sorting arrays, not numbers. When you give an example it's essential that you show the desired return value, which you have not done (and it's not obvious), but I think you would need a few examples and the desired result for each ito make the question clear. For exampel, suppose `ary = [3, 6, 7], [8, 1, 9], [6, 8, 2]]`. Are we to compare `[3, ∞, 7], [∞, 1, 9], [2]]`  (`∞` being `Float:INFINITY`) or `[3, 7], [1, 9], [2]]` or something else?

Comment: There is small type I guess in second code line as `b:odd?`, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your original question, just as axiac points out in the comment, the result of the sorting should be exactly the same as the input array because they are all sorted by the first odd element in each subarray, which is `1`, and the sort method is stable in MRI.

---

Regarding your question after the edit, my answer would be:

```
ary.sort_by{|a| a[0...-1].select(&:odd?) << a.last}
# => [[1, 8, 3], [1, 6, 7], [1, 4, 9]]
```

I am pretty confident that this is what you wrote after the edit that you wanted, but I am not sure if this is what you wanted since the sorting mechanism looks strange to me.

Comment: Indeed! I do not know whether this is what OP intend to do but it is surely something that OP asked. Nice implementation done at edit!

Comment: Thanks for this one-liner. As I'm sure is entirely not to anyone's surprise, I'm very new to Ruby. I'm not new to explaining problems, though, and I did a bad job here. I sure appreciate everyone's help, and next time I have a question I'll ask it more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

I find the statement of the question ambiguous. I will give an answer that is consist with one interpretation. If that is not what you want, please clarify hte question.

```
def my_sort(arr)
  arr.sort_by {|a| a.any?(&:odd?) ? a.map {|e| e.odd? ? e : Float::INFINITY} : [a.last]}
end

my_sort [[1, 6, 7], [1, 4, 9], [1, 2, 3]]
  #=>   [[1, ∞, 7], [1, ∞, 9], [1, ∞, 3]] (sort_by)
  #=>   [[1, 2, 3], [1, 6, 7], [1, 4, 9]]
my_sort [[3, 6, 7], [4, 1, 9], [5, 8, 1]]
  #=>   [[3, ∞, 7], [∞, 1, 9], [5, ∞, 1]] (sort_by) 
  #=>   [[3, 6, 7], [5, 8, 1], [4, 1, 9]] 
my_sort [[2, 6, 8], [4, 1, 4], [8, 6, 2]]
  #=>   [[8],       [∞, 1, ∞], [2]]       (sort_by) 
  #=>   [[8, 6, 2], [2, 6, 8], [4, 1, 4]] 
my_sort [[8, 6, 2], [5, 1, 1], [6, 8, 4]]
  #=>   [[2],       [5, 1, 1], [4]        (sort_by) 
  #=>   [[8, 6, 2], [6, 8, 4], [5, 1, 1]]
```

For each example I've shown the arrays used by `sort_by` to produce the sort shown on the following line.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Next time I ask a question I'll be more careful with it.